# How do I automate disabling mobile data on Lollipop?

Tags: mobile-data, automation, 5.1-lollipop

I have recently changed my Moto G LTE (XT1039) from Android 4.x to 5.1. The device is not rooted.

After the update, I found that [Llama - Location Profiles](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kebab.Llama)'s toggle mobile data - mobile data off action fails to disable my mobile data.

After checking out a few alternatives, I found that several automation apps have reviews mentioning a similar situation. For example [Data ON-OFF](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=it.miabit.android.dataonoff&reviewId=Z3A6QU9xcFRPR0FFMW5wM1F6SnBCWTBQR3JXZ3k0aFd0cHRsRzJFOEtxcEk0ZENxSm5RT1hBcjBfZ0JNcEJLVjNVTGphYnladHpmVHR0aGlfRjh0dmF6SVE) has this review:

> Not working 5.1 motto 4g Used to work on 4.4.4 uninstalled until it gets an update.

How do I automate the toggling of mobile data on/off in Android 5.1?

Or, has there been a change to the Android API to remove this functionality?

Comment: How or when exactly do you want to toggle or disable mobile data? Please mention those details. Other than that, is the device rooted?

Comment: Device is not rooted. I like to turn of data before midnight to minimise charges.

Comment: Sorry to be the bearer of bad news: but without root, you won't be able to do that anymore. One of the big "new features" of each Android version is that it takes one of those toggles out of the reach of apps and automation. With Lollipop, that was "mobile data". Only root apps can toggle that now.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) which is paid but really powerful app.

- You can create a profile based on an event, schedule, or according to your preference.
- Then you can create a task with an action from Net > Mobile Data section.

Note: this action requires either root, [ADB WiFi](https://tasker.joaoapps.com/userguide/en/help/ah_adb_wifi.html) to be enabled, or permission to [write secure settings](https://tasker.joaoapps.com/userguide/en/help/ah_secure_setting_grant.html).

Answer (score 0):

"Toggle Data 5.0" appears to be an app/widget that should do what you are asking.

The app is paid (but free on [XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/apps-games/app-toggle-data-5-0-widget-to-toggle-t2937936)) and requires root. Hope this helps. =)

Answer (score 0):

[Automate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.llamalab.automate) can toggle [Mobile data](http://llamalab.com/automate/doc/block/mobile_data_set_state.html), however it require a rooted device since Android 5. It can likely be done on unrooted device as well, using [UI automation](http://llamalab.com/automate/doc/block/interact.html).