# Is it possible to automatically disabling mobile data when connected to anyone Wi-Fi?

Tags: wi-fi, mobile-data, automation, mobile-network

I regularly forget to turn off mobile data after connecting to Wi-Fi. It's not just a waste of battery, it's mainly a problem with random signal fluctuations (especially on public Wi-Fi) where it sometimes disconnects and doesn't automatically reconnect, resulting in me re-using limited mobile data, which I don't want.

Is it possible to turn off mobile data automatically, please?

**UPDATE:**

I ended up using the [MacroDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid&hl=en&gl=US) app which has a free version. It can also deactivate mobile data using an **adb hack** without the need to root the phone (which I failed to do anyway). How to do this is shown in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_WLbhtpC5ls).

The problem is that it can only be set on a specific Wi-Fi. So, every time I connect to a different Wi-Fi than home, I have to add it there.

Is there any way to solve this, please?

Comment: Try an automation app from Play Store. Use trigger as "Wifi connected" and action as "turn off mobile data".

Comment: Mostly related: [How do I automate disabling mobile data on Lollipop?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/113645/44325)

Comment: @AndrewT. Thank you, but as you can see from the question, mobile data can only be controlled automatically with ROOT permission. I honestly don't know if I should do something like this? It's not about the warranty, it's more about safety.

Comment: I have personally tried the Tasker answer on Android 12, and it works on an unrooted device but requires to allow permission to write secure settings using ADB.

Comment: @AndrewT. Yes, I read that, but that one is paid. Is there a free alternative please?